# How can I show $1-(a/b)^{3/2} \approx (3/2) (b-a)/b$ for $ a/b \approx 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'd like to show that

$$1-\left(\frac ab\right)^{3/2} \approx \tfrac 32\cdot \frac{b-a}{b}$$

I first thought of binomial series, but I can now see it doesn't fit.
Can anyone help?

Tks

Comment: Under what conditions on $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I´ve changed the enouncement. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on in what values of $x:=\frac ab$ you are interested (such as $x\gg1$ or $x\approx 1$ or $x\approx 0$ or ...).
I shall assume $x\approx 1$, because that's where the result holds.
The Binomial series works, not only for integral exponent, where for $x\approx 1$ we write $x=1+h$ with $h\approx 0$.
In fact, we it suffices to use the versions with integral exponents: 
With $y=\sqrt x=1+k$ we have $x=y^2\approx 1+2k$, hence $h\approx \frac12k$ and 
$$ x^{3/2}=y^3\approx 1+3k\approx 1+\frac32h$$
Hence
$$ 1-x^{3/2}\approx \frac32(1-x)$$

Comment: You assumed it correctly. I forgot to put $a/b \approx 1$.